# What's the price for referencial integrity of database tables on Android?

Tags: android, sqlite

Well, the title says it all - does `pragma foreign_keys = true` to an existing database makes my database "less fast"?

Comment: Will it be slower? Yes, extra checks mean extra time needed. By how much? I don't know. Best to do some experiments.

Comment: Of course.  Its now doing something it wasn't previously doing.  Is it worth the cost?  Depends on the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever data is added, removed, or changed, the database needs to check that the constraints still hold. The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_indexes) lists some examples of how these checks look like.

In practice, it is very likely that you will need to access all the referenced tables anyway, so everything will be in the cache.
Furthermore, the biggest slowdown if a database write is the transaction overhead. So it is likely that the additional checking does not lead to a noticeable delay.

In any case, SELECT queries are not affected by foreign key constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Although the accepted answer is sufficient, I want to put here one specific use case.

For anyone who has to imply foreign keys constraint to an existing database and probably needs to do some refactoring of the database, call `setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled` in the `onOpen` method of the `SQLiteOpenHelper`.

From the book [Android Enterprise](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Enterprise-Android-Programming-Android-Database-Applications-for-the-Enterprise.productCd-1118183495.html):

> The onOpen method is called only after onCreate, onUpgrade, and onDowngrade, leaving
>   those methods free to play fast and loose while they rebuild the schema. The occasion in
>   which an application must rename or recreate a table or two during an upgrade might be
>   one of the few times that it is truly a relief that foreign key constraints are not enforced.
>   Enabling foreign key constraints in the onOpen method causes them to be enforced only
>   after the database has been initialized.